# Using supertest and async.parallel to send parallel http requests?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, supertest

I found an interesting bug during exploratory testing that occurs when parallel/concurrent requests are sent to the application. I am trying to replicate the scenario with test automation using supertest, but I am doing something wrong using the async library. Can anyone let me know what I am missing?

```js
it('will handle concurrent GET requests', function(done){
     var asyncTasks = [];

     for (i = 0; i < 30; i++){
      asyncTasks.push(function(done){
        agent.get('url')
      .set('headerHere', 'someVal')
      .send('')
      .expect(200, done);
       })
      };

     async.parallel(asyncTasks, function(){
      done();
     });
 })
```

It either isn't asserting the expected code or not running the task at all from what I can tell.

Comment: It seems you do not handle errors in async.parallel callback. You're just calling done whether or not an error occured.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you do not handle errors in async.parallel callback. You're just calling done whether or not an error occured. The code below should pass asyncTask error to parallel `done` callback method.

```
it('will handle concurrent GET requests', function(done){
    var asyncTasks = [];

    for (i = 0; i < 30; i++){
        asyncTasks.push(function(done){
                agent.get('api/vault?partition=test')
                    .set('headerHere', 'someVal')
                    .send('')
                    .expect(200, done);
            })
        };

    async.parallel(asyncTasks, done);
})
```

By the way, take a look at [async.times](https://github.com/caolan/async#times) method. It can make your code shorter and easier to read.

```
it('will handle concurrent GET requests', function(done){
    var asyncTask = function(done){
        agent.get('api/vault?partition=test')
            .set('headerHere', 'someVal')
            .send('')
            .expect(200, done);
        });
    };

    async.times(30, asyncTask, done);
})
```

Comment: This was great information. I found out one extra modification I needed to make because done wasn't being called when the test was passing. I added a counter to call done once all requests were processed.

Answer (score 1):

ezrepotein4 got me on the right track. Here is the full answer I went with.

```js
it('will handle concurrent GET requests', function(done){

  var parallelRuns = 100;
  var actualRuns = 0;

     var asyncTask = function(err, result){
        agent.get('url')
             .set('someHeader', 'someValue')
             .send('')
             .expect(200)
             .end(function(err, res){
              actualRuns++;

           if (err) {
            return done(err);
           }

           if (actualRuns == parallelRuns){
            done();
           }

       });
     }

     async.times(parallelRuns, asyncTask, done);
 })
```